# command output get into an array

Tags: arrays

I want to store elements of boot command. I tried this :

But it doesn't work. I want to store  elements of  last reboot command. How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want reboot times you can use awk like this:

```
# change internal field separator to newline because awk will write each date on new lines
_IFS=$IFS;
IFS=$'\n';
# Grep all lines that starts with reboot, then remove the first 2 fields and print the rest
reboots=($(last | awk '/^reboot/{$1=$2="";print}'));
# Reset IFS
IFS=_IFS;

echo ${reboots[0]}; # Mon Jul 13 10:39
echo ${reboots[1]}; # Mon Jul xx xx:xx
echo ${reboots[2]}; # Mon Jul xx xx:xx
echo ${reboots[...]}; # Mon Jul xx xx:xx
```

Answer (score 0):

To split a string into an array using IFS as a separator, you can enclose it in parenthesis:

```
my_array=($(last -F | grep reboot))
echo "${my_array[@]}"
```

Comment: Okey thank you. It helps me . So if I store an array line by line, do I use awk or something different ? Do you have any idea ?